# Will Amazon Cognito Provide any control over the federated identities?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, federated-identity

Will Amazon Cognito Provide any control over the federated identities?
I want to able to block a google or Salesforce user.
I don't to allow some federated guy entering.

Comment: Are you talking about Amazon Cognito Federated Identities (identity pools) or Amazon Cognito User Pools.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, developers configure the federated identity providers they want to use for each User Pool, and they can choose for each app client, which identity providers are offered.  (Assuming you are asking federation with Cognito User Pools)